# TF Merge Command

Tags: tfs, merge, tfs-2010

I use the following command to merge a single changeset from Source to target branch:

```
result = BatchCommand(@"tf merge /version:" + chgnumber + "~" + chgnumber + @" """ + Source + @""" """ + Target + @""" /recursive /login:" + UID + "," + PWD + "", SourceTar[2]);
```

BatchCommand is another method which executes the command in cmd in my workspace SourceTar[2].
in some cases I get the error where I need to overwrite files. How can I do this automatically (Overwrite files).

Should I use /force for that? It definetly will resolve that overwrite conflict but will it also resolve other conflict(I don't want that).

I only want to overwrite files if that error occurs, other conflicts are resolved programmatically. Any suggestion would be helpful;

Comment: Whih version of TFS are you using?

Comment: TFS 2010.. mentioned in tag

Answer (score 3):

You need to work with **[tf resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy(v=vs.100).aspx)** command to resolve conflicts. Your commands can be the similar to:

`tf merge $/TeamProjectRoot/Branches/Source $/TeamProjectRoot/Branches/Target`
`tf resolve $/TeamProjectRoot/Branches/Target /r /i /auto:TakeTheirs`

`/auto:TakeTheirs` option accepts the changes from the source of the merge and overwrites the changes in the target.
`/auto:KeepYours` option discards the changes from the source of the merge and leaves the target unchanged.

Comment: What are the r and I switches for?